# Javascript function does not execute on page load

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create a dynamic list-group with list-group-items that are loaded on page load. The list group items are taken from a database. The php function returns an array of courses (this works successfully). I used Javascript to take this array, JSON encode it and display the items in a list-group, but the Javascript code is not working. I have used `<body onload="get_courses()">` but this does not work on page load. However if I use `<body onload="alert('test');">`, it works, but the alert inside the function does not work. 
My code is as below. I have the Javascript code in the same html file.

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_courses(){
    var service = <?php echo json_encode(get_course_list($userID)); ?>;
    var course_array = JSON.parse(service);
    var index;
    var ul = document.getElementById("course_list");
    for (index=0; index<course_array.length; index++){
        var li = document.createElement("a");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(course_array[index]));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
</script>
```

**html**

```
<body onload="get_courses()">
    <form action="../../controller/progressTeacherControl.php" method="get">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="list-group" id="course_list">
                <!--a href="#" class="list-group-item">This would be a generated course name</a-->
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</body>
```

progressTeacherControl.php is where the php function get_course_list() is defined. 
Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that your `var service`... is bad in that it lacks any quotation marks and unless the PHP outputs them, it would produce an invalid code. Open your JS error console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Firefox) to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, but I couldn't find a solution to the above. However, I found a workaround using php to get the data that I want, and it is much easier to use as well. The code is as below:

**php**

```
<form action="student_progress_allstudents.php" method="get">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="list-group" id="course_list">
            <?php
            foreach(get_course_list($userID) as $block) {
                list($section, $course, $course_id) = explode(" ", $block); ?>    
                <a href="student_progress_allstudents.php?c_id=<?php echo $course_id ?>" class="list-group-item">
                    <?= $course ?>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing JSON there, then it will already be in a format suitable for JavaScript. It will print as a literal array.

So drop the `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you comment out all your code in the function and put the alert() in there, does it run?

Also, console.log() is less annoying than having to close the alert.